# Couldn't find any package by regex - ruby

Tags: installation, 12.10, apt, ruby

I need to install `ruby1.9.3-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby1.9.3-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby1.9.3-dev'
```

It happens despite the fact that I previously did `sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: What is `ruby1.9.3-dev`?  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&keywords=ruby1.9.3-dev&searchon=names shows no results... it does have a `ruby1.9.3` http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/precise/ruby1.9.3 Are you sure you do not mean ruby1.9.1-dev ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Ruby on Ubuntu 12.10, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

To Install Gems

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

To install all of Rails and its dependencies

```
sudo gem install rails
```

For more info check the [Ruby Website](http://rubyonrails.org/download)

From researching, it says that ruby1.9.3-dev doesn't exist. And that ruby1.9.1-dev is its alias. Here is what I've done.  I installed ruby as stated above, and then ran the command `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3-dev`, and I got the same error.  But when I ran sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev, this is what I got:

[image]

Comment: it's already installed via rvm.

Comment: From researching, it says that ruby1.9.3-dev doesn't exist.  And that ruby1.9.1-dev is its alias.  See the update in my answer.