# ERROR: While executing gem (some::Gem) no such name (http://some.url)

Tags: ruby, software-installation

I'm trying to install rails using

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
no such name (https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/activerecord-4.0.2.gemspec.rz
```

What am I doing wrong? do I have to use **sudo apt-get install rails** instead?

I have in my system

```
$ ruby -v
> 2.1.11
$ gem -v 
> ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
```

I'm following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284459/couldnt-find-any-package-by-regex-ruby/284471#284471)

**Solved**

How did I solved it?

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284459/couldnt-find-any-package-by-regex-ruby/284471#284471) as **Mitch** advised me, but after `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3` I got that `ruby -v` showed `ruby 1.8.7`

So I did [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91693/how-do-you-uninstall-ruby-1-8-7-and-install-ruby-1-9-2#answer-91780) and then I continue with

```
sudo gem install rails
```

it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate for the same: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158686/rails-error-while-executing-gemremotefetcherunknownhosterror

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/284459/couldnt-find-any-package-by-regex-ruby/284471#284471

Comment: @Mitch I did that but when I try `sudo gem install rails` it does nothing

Comment: After see your edit, **please create a new answer**. Don't write it on the *question*!

Comment: @Lucio I tried but my reputation is so slow

Comment: Really? Could you show me an screenshoot of the message that you get when trying to answer your own post? Upload it into imgur.com and link it here

Comment: @Lucio now I can. It's my first post here so yesterday my reputacion was 1(too slow). That's why I guess I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did I solved it?

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284459/couldnt-find-any-package-by-regex-ruby/284471#284471) as **Mitch** advised me, but after `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3` I got that `ruby -v` showed `ruby 1.8.7`

So I did [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91693/how-do-you-uninstall-ruby-1-8-7-and-install-ruby-1-9-2#answer-91780) and then I continue with

```
sudo gem install rails
```

it worked.